# Create row in Excel with duplicate's data

Tags: excel

So I needed to make a sheet for uploading some products, some of those products are grouped products. To make my importer work I need to take these grouped products and create a new row for them. All the grouped ids are in a column mixed with non grouped ids. I also have a column with the individual ids.

Sample data ids and grouped ids columns:

```
AR1249-16   AR1249
AR1253-16   AR1253
AR1359-04   AR1359
AR1373-18   AR1373
AR1424-03   AR1424
AR1424-07   AR1424
AR1454-16   AR1454
AR1470-01   AR1470
AR1507-03   AR1507
AR1511-16   AR1511
AR1531-03   AR1531
AR1576-03   AR1576
AR1578-03   AR1578
AR1589-03   AR1589
AR1618-03   AR1618
AR1618-14   AR1618
AR1630-06   AR1630
AR1682-06   AR1682
AR1696-03   AR1696
AR1732-03   AR1732
AR1800-03   AR1800
AR1800-04   AR1800
AR1800-05   AR1800
AR1800-10   AR1800
AR1800-48   AR1800
AR1803-16   AR1803
AR1804-03   AR1804
AR1804-04   AR1804
AR1804-05   AR1804
AR1804-10   AR1804
AR1804-48   AR1804
AR1804-06   AR1804
```

The Question: 
What I'd like to do is use some sort or filter function with Excel that reads this column, finds the duplicates in the grouped ids, and make a new row with the individual ids of those grouped products.

I've searched far and wide for possible solutions but since Excel is so widely used I couldn't find the gem between all the rubbish.

The output at the end of the sheet could look like this per example:

```
"AR1424", "AR1424-03, AR1424-07"
"AR1618", "AR1618-03, AR1618-14"
"AR1800", "AR1800-03, AR1800-04, AR1800-05, AR1800-10, AR1800-48"
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect the output to be?  I see for example that `AR1800` has multiple entries.  I don't quite understand what you want to output based on those repeats.  A new sheet with `AR1800-03, AR1800-04, etc.` listed?  Also, are you trying to do this with formulas or VBA or does it matter?

Comment: Yes offcourse, it doesn't really matter what's used. i'll take a look at VBA since i don't know it though. Maybe i'll even find an answer who knows.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/621124-function-concatenate-string-if-same-group.html) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table), What we are trying to do is "group by concatenate strings"

Comment: I made it work with the second link you posted @zx8754 , Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this post is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with VBA instead of formulas, here is one route that makes use of `AutoFilter` on each unique entry and then processing the visible cells onto another sheet.  The ranges and names are specific to the application above but could be changed to suit.

**Code**

```
Sub GroupByCommonValue()

    Dim rng_all As Range
    Set rng_all = Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    Dim rng_data As Range
    Set rng_data = Intersect(rng_all, rng_all.Offset(1))

    'create output sheet
    Dim sht_out As Worksheet
    Set sht_out = Worksheets.Add()
    sht_out.Range("A1") = "GROUP"
    sht_out.Range("B1") = "IDs"

    Dim rng_out As Range
    Set rng_out = sht_out.Range("A2")

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In rng_data
        'skip duplicates
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng_out.EntireColumn, rng.Value) = 0 Then

            rng_all.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=rng.Value

            Dim arr As Variant
            arr = rng_data.Offset(, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

            rng_out = rng.Value

            If TypeName(arr) <> "Variant()" Then
                rng_out.Offset(, 1) = arr
            Else
                arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

                'top line will concatenate / lower will create column for each
                rng_out.Offset(, 1) = Join(arr, ", ")
                'rng_out.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = arr
            End If

            Set rng_out = rng_out.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next

    rng_all.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

**Couple notes on the code**

- Using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to check if the value appears on the output sheet before doing the filter.  Avoids extra work.
- `SpecialCells` returns the visible cells only.  If there are multiple values, then `Value` will return a `Variant()` array.  If it is not that type, then there is only a single cell to move over.
- For the array, you can either use `Join` to concatenate it all together or output it to different columns (currently commented out).

**Pictures of before and after (on a new sheet)**

[image]
[image]